Invalid async invocation in dotnet-isolated Azure Function project when calling a sub orchestrator
This is a .net8, Azure Functions v4, dotnet-isolated project.  I'm getting the following exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'An invalid asynchronous invocation was detected. This can be caused by awaiting non-durable tasks in an orchestrator function's implementation or by middleware that invokes asynchronous code.'

To my knowledge there is no middleware
This happens when adding the sub orchestrator task to parallelTasks.  I've attempted to make the code as minimal as possible, even hardcoding a return value from the sub orchestrator to remove any async calls.  Normally the sub orchestrator has a ctx.CallHttpAsync() method in it but the same exception happens when I await that.
As this is an upgrade to dotnet isolated I feel like I'm missing something obvious here - thank you for any help!
This is the Orchestrator:
public async Task<bool> StudentEnrollmentUpdated(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext ctx,
    StudentEnrollment studentEnrollment,
    FunctionContext executionContext
)
{
...
...
  var parallelTasks = new Task<PlatformEnrollmentMessage>[pqcs.Count];
  ServiceBusMessageBatch batch = await _sender.CreateMessageBatchAsync();
  try
  {
     for (var i = 0; i < pqcs.Count; i++)
     {
        var inputs = new CreatePlatformEnrollmentMessageInputs()
        {
            QuizConfiguration = pqcs[i],
            User = ltiUser,
            Enrollment = studentEnrollment,
            DeliveryData = customData
        };
        parallelTasks[i] = ctx.CallSubOrchestratorAsync<PlatformEnrollmentMessage>("SO_CreatePlatformEnrollmentMessage", inputs);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    var d = true;
  }
  await Task.WhenAll(parallelTasks);
...
}

And this is the SubOrchestrator
[Function("SO_CreatePlatformEnrollmentMessage")]
public async Task<PlatformEnrollmentMessage> CreatePlatformEnrollmentMessage(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext ctx,
    CreatePlatformEnrollmentMessageInputs inputs
)
{
    return new PlatformEnrollmentMessage
    {
        Id = 123,
        PlatformQuizConfigurationId = 456,
        UserId = 1
    };
}


Can you share your full code?

Try using await here var inputs = new CreatePlatformEnrollmentMessageInputs()

@VivekVaibhavShandilya CreatePlatformEnrollmentMessageInputs is just a POCO with 4 properties - no constructors or methods.

use await when you are calling a suborchestrator. parallelTasks[i] = await ctx.CallSubOrchestratorAsync<PlatformEnrollmentMessage>("SO_CreatePlatformEnrollmentMessage", inputs);

await for all suborchestrator call to becompleted using var result = await Task.WhenAll(parallelTasks);

The code does use await Task.WhenAll(parallelTasks) but it never gets to that point.  I don't think you're correct that you should await when adding the tasks to the list of tasks.

did you try adding await to when calling suborchestrator?

I will try - but that defeats the purpose of the pattern, no? Because you're now awaiting the work to complete instead of building a list of all the work to be done, and then awaiting.  It's the fan in/out pattern.
In other words - you don't need to await the suborchestrator and call Task.WhenAll


@ChrisRockwell  Did you resolve it ? what is the fix ?


@S2K I did find a resolution, but now I'm not sure what it is - I forgot about this issue :/.  Looking at my code now, I think it might have had something to do with creating the logger - are you experiencing a similar issue? Can you share any code? I'm happy to take a look and see if anything triggers my memory.
